# Import vector shapes from photoshop to flash cs5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-flash

How can I Import vector shapes from photoshop to flash cs5.

I have tried to export an .ai file, and Import it in flash but that doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bring it into Illustrator first by doing Save As .eps include vector information. Once its in illustrator you can easily bring it into Flash.

If you export as .ai you could also open it in illustrator first and then bring it into Flash but you'll lose fill styles doing it that way.